# How do I put text on symbols without destroying table-form of equation?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I want to put text on top of an equality symbol AND have mulitple equations in a table-like style where all equality symbols are below each other.
I have tried using `\overset{ sometext }{=}` from the `amsmath` package but this "destroyed" the arrangement as it shifted the equality symbols to make the text on top be in line with the other equality smybols:

[image]

Here my corresponding code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    x+2 &= 4-2 \\
    &\overset{sometext}{=} 2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If is is really text (and not a pure math subformula) you should use `\text{some text}`. This being said, for your specific problem, you can use `\overset{\makebox[0pt]{some text}{=}`.

Comment: IMO such annotations belong on a blackboard, not in typeset text. Write it in an explanation between the line via `\intertext{sometext}`

Comment: Thank you Bernard and daleif! I should have specified that I meant to only put a reference of a definition on top of the equality symbol and not long text for explanation. Your suggestion works perfectly for me though, Bernard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as the "sometext" text string isn't too long, the following approach may be useful. (The `\downarrow` symbol is optional.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\mathclap" macro
  % mathtools package loads amsmath package automatically
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    x+2 &= 4-2 \\
    &\overset{\substack{%
        \mathclap{\text{\tiny sometext}}\\ 
        \downarrow}}{=} 2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```